# xsl fo base link problem with password protected pdf in fop 0.95

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have successfully generated password protected pdf using xsl fo from apache foundation's fop 0.95 engine. Now the problem comes with the base-link with external-destination specified. Clicking the links work no more. On hover, the link shows the tooltip of the form: "file:///C:/myfolder/some-strange-special-characters". However, this works successfully with the normal unprotected pdf, and on hover shows the following tooltip: "http://www.mysite.com". What should I do?

I use the following command line option to generate password protected pdf from xml using fop 0.95:

```
fop.bat -u myPassword -xml sample.xml -xsl sample.xsl -pdf sample.pdf
```

The syntax for placing link is:

```
<fo:block>
   <fo:base-link external-destination="http://www.mysite.com"></fo:base-link>
</fo:block>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looks like a bug in FOP:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31039

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug that is fixed but not actually released :/

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-916

EDIT: the fix for this bug was included in FOP 2.2